# .gsub erroring with non-regular character 194

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string

I've seen this posted a couple of times but none of the solutions seem to work for me so far...

I'm trying to remove a spurious Â character from a string...

e.g.

```
"myÂstring here Â$100"
```

..but it should be `my string here $100`

I've tried:

```
string.gsub(/\194/,'')
string.gsub(194.chr,'')
string.delete 194.chr
```

All of these still leave the Â intact..

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rails supports UTF-8.

You can use your favorite editor to write a `gsub` call using the proper character you want to replace, as in:

```
"myÂstring here Â$100".gsub(/Â/,"")
```

If this does not work as well, you might be having an encoding error somewhere on your stack, probably on your HTML document. Try running `rails console`, extract somehow that string (if it comes from the Model, try to perform a `find` on the containing class) and run the `gsub`. It won't solve your problem, but you'll get a clue to where exactly the problem may lie.

Comment: pretty sure this has resolved it thanks, I had tried .gsub("Â","")  rather than .gsub(/Â/,"") which I had assumed would work the same way... just going to try a few tests to see if this has resolved it

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a character encoding problem to me.  For every Unicode code point in the range `U+0080..U+00BF` inclusive, the UTF-8 encoding is a two-byte sequence, `0xC2` (194 decimal) and the numeric value the code point.  For example, a non-breaking space--`U+00A0`--becomes `0xC2 0xA0`.  Was there another extra character in there, that you already removed?

At any rate, `gsub(/\194/,'')` is wrong.  `\nnn` is supposed to be an octal escape, but the number is in its decimal form.  194 in octal is `\302`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"myÂstring here Â$100".gsub("Â","") # "mystring here $100"
```

Is that what you meant?